# Provide documentation for ASP.NET Web Api method with a dynamic query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using [Help Pages for ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages) to create documentation for our web api. Everything is working fine using the XML documentation comments. However, for one method I can't figure out how to supply documentation for a dynamic query string. 
The method uses the `GetQueryNameValuePairs()` of the request to select the key-value pairs of the query string to a model. For example `?1=foo&2=bar` will result in a list of two objects with Id set to 1 and 2 and Value to 'foo' and 'bar', respectively.

I've tried adding the `<param>` tag to the XML comment, but this is ignored since the method does not contain a matching parameter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could try extending the help page generation process. When you create your ASP.NET Web API project, the help page-related code is downloaded as source, not as a `.dll`, so you can extend it with any custom logic you'd like.

Here's what I would do:

1. Create an `attribute` class and decorate my special method with that (e.g.  `[DynamicQueryParameter("Param1",typeof(string))]`)
2. Modify the `HelPageConfigurationExtensions.cs` to query these attributes from the actions as well and add them manually to the `UriParameters` collection of the model. I would probably do this in the `GenerateUriParameters()` method.

[Edit] I actually had some time, so I put together the solution myself, because, you know, it's fun :)

So create an an `attribute`:

```
public class DynamicUriParameterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

You can decorate your action methods with this:

```
[DynamicUriParameter(Description = "Some description", Name ="Some name", Type =typeof(string))]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
  return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Then I modified the `HelpPageConfigurationExtensions.GenerateApiModel()` like this:

```
private static HelpPageApiModel GenerateApiModel(ApiDescription apiDescription, HttpConfiguration config)
{
   HelpPageApiModel apiModel = new HelpPageApiModel()
   {
      ApiDescription = apiDescription,
   };


ModelDescriptionGenerator modelGenerator = config.GetModelDescriptionGenerator();
HelpPageSampleGenerator sampleGenerator = config.GetHelpPageSampleGenerator();            
GenerateUriParameters(apiModel, modelGenerator);

// add this part
var attrs = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<DynamicUriParameterAttribute>();
foreach (var attr in attrs)
{
    apiModel.UriParameters.Add(
       new ParameterDescription
       {
           Name = attr.Name,
           Documentation = attr.Description,
           TypeDescription = modelGenerator.GetOrCreateModelDescription(attr.Type)
       }
     );
  }
  // until here
  GenerateRequestModelDescription(apiModel, modelGenerator, sampleGenerator);
  GenerateResourceDescription(apiModel, modelGenerator);
  GenerateSamples(apiModel, sampleGenerator);

  return apiModel;
}
```